# Show that $k\ln k \in \Theta(n)$ implies $k \in \Theta(n/\ln(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

It is exercise (3.2-8) from Introduction to Algorithms book.
I need help to solve it.

I am confused by the fact that there are two parameters. Because usually one parameter is used.
There is related exercise

> [image]
>   which can be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The question in the title is not related to that exercise: here there is only one parameter $n$, and $k$ is supposed to depend on $n$.

Comment: Are you sure? Because if $k$ is function of $n$ then it should be $k(n)$.

Comment: If $k$ is not a function of $n$ then $k\ln k$ is a constant with respect to $n$, and thus necessarily in $\Theta(n)$; then it wouldn't make any sense to say something about what this "implies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call this rigorous, but here's an idea:

If $f \in\Theta(g)$, say $f \sim g$.

So we have $n \sim k\ln k$ and want to show $n/\ln n \sim k$.  Well if $n \sim k\ln k$, then $\ln n \sim \ln (k \ln k) \sim \ln k + \ln \ln k \sim \ln k$.
**Note: this requires rigorous justification, and I'm not exactly sure it's right**

So  $n/ \ln n \sim k \ln k / \ln k \sim k$

Answer (score 0):

$$c_1n \leq klnk \leq c_2n$$
$$ln(c_1n) \leq ln(klnk) \leq ln(c_2n)
\\ln c_1 + ln n \leq  lnk + lnlnk \leq lnc_2 + ln n\\
\frac{1}{2}ln n \leq ln n + lnlnk \leq 2lnn\\
\therefore lnk +lnlnk = \Theta(ln n)\\
and\\ lnk \leq lnk+ ln lnk \leq 2lnk\\
\therefore ln k + lnlnk \Theta(ln k)\\
reflexivity \implies\\
ln k = \Theta(lnk+ lnlnk)\\
transitivity \implies\\
lnk = \Theta(lnn)\\
$$
$$c_1n \leq klnk\\
c_2lnn \geq ln k\\
\frac{c_1n}{c_2lnn} \leq k$$